# Unity Sphere Collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics

I know Unity has a lot of ways of working out whether or not an object is inside another object, whether or not they are touching etc., but what I'm wanting to know is something a bit more specific.

In my research I found out about [Physics.OverlappedSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) and from what I can read this gives you information about every object with a collider within the sphere. What I would like to know is if I had two spheres which made use of Physics.OverlappedSphere, could I find out at which point(s) these spheres meet and intersect?

If this isn't possible, can someone suggest another way I may be able to find out this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Collision class and therein the Collision.contacts (which is an array of contactpoints) you should be able to...

[Taken from here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collision-contacts.html)

```
function OnCollisionStay(collision : Collision) {
    for (var contact : ContactPoint in collision.contacts) {
        print(contact.thisCollider.name + " hit " + contact.otherCollider.name);
        // Visualize the contact point
        Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, contact.normal, Color.white);
    }
}
```

Try getting the size of the contacts array and look at the last points.

```
// Print how many points are colliding this transform 
// And print the first point that is colliding.
function OnCollisionEnter(other : Collision) {
    print("Points colliding: " + other.contacts.Length);
    print("First point that collided: " + other.contacts[0].point);
}
```